# dpkg does not work using Termux Ubuntu installation, returns tar errors and exits with error code 1

Tags: termux

I have tried to use Termux to install Ubuntu on ChromeOS without developer mode or root priveleges, and was successful up to this point. I accessed an Ubuntu shell from Termux but `dpkg` returns this error for any package, rendering the system useless:

```
root@localhost:~# apt install nano
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  spell
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nano
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 243 kB of archives.
After this operation, 823 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 nano i386 2.9.3-2 [243 kB]
Fetched 243 kB in 1s (198 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
E: Setting in Start via TCSAFLUSH for stdin failed! - tcsetattr (13: Permission denied)
dpkg-deb: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for tar subprocess failed: Unknown error 512
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nano_2.9.3-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nano_2.9.3-2_i386.deb
tar: .: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: ./conffiles: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: ./control: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: ./md5sums: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: ./postinst: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: ./prerm: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: How exactly did you "access" Ubuntu shell? How did you switch from ChromeOS environment to Ubuntu? Chroot? Namespaces? OverlayFS? How did you run `apt` without root privileges on Ubuntu?

Comment: tcsetattr 13 Permission denied says you don't have write permissions, which means no root or selinux restrictions https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1359

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install nano
```

You can't use `apt` without superuser (root) privilegies.